# How to get information of the error using Valgrind?

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

my code, written in C and C++, reports a segmentation fault.
If I replace, in the main function, the statement "return 0;" with "exit(0);", the project execution is stopped successfully at the exit instruction.
To have an idea where the error is, I used valgrind.
The final error of the log file of valgrind execution is:

```
==23354== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==23354==    at 0x1700000007: ???
==23354==    by 0x1800000007: ???
==23354==    by 0x1900000008: ???
==23354==    by 0x1A00000009: ???
==23354==    by 0x1B0000000A: ???
==23354==    by 0x1C0000000B: ???
==23354==    by 0x1D0000000C: ???
==23354==    by 0x1F0000000E: ???
==23354==    by 0xFFFFFFFFF: ???
==23354==    by 0x1100000000: ???
==23354==    by 0x1200000001: ???
==23354==    by 0x1300000002: ???
==23354==  Address 0x1700000007 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==23354== 
==23354== 
==23354== Process terminating with default action of signal 11     (SIGSEGV)
==23354==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x1700000007
==23354==    at 0x1700000007: ???
==23354==    by 0x1800000007: ???
==23354==    by 0x1900000008: ???
==23354==    by 0x1A00000009: ???
==23354==    by 0x1B0000000A: ???
==23354==    by 0x1C0000000B: ???
==23354==    by 0x1D0000000C: ???
==23354==    by 0x1F0000000E: ???
==23354==    by 0xFFFFFFFFF: ???
==23354==    by 0x1100000000: ???
==23354==    by 0x1200000001: ???
==23354==    by 0x1300000002: ???
```

I really don't know how to interpret this question marks.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `written in C` __and__ `C++,`...how's that?

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else. The `return 0`/`exit(0)` aren't the ones causing it. Show us the code.

Comment: Point 1) use `gdb` first. Point 2) compile with debugging flag, `-g` enabled for debugging binaries. Point 3) See the above comment by @CoolGuy.

Comment: Generally speaking, *first* errors are much more interesting than *last* errors. Last errors are usually follow-ups that do not tell you anything about the reason.

Comment: If gdb doens't tell you where the problem is(memory overwrite or something else), start removing 50% of the code until the problem goes away. Then add 50% of the last change and so on until you've narrowed it down.

Comment: You are missing the debug symbols of the code, compile it with -g or install that information. Productive binaries usually have that information stripped.

Comment: @SouravGhosh `C++` is largely (although technically not) a superset of `C`. Thus, if the code is legal `C` and `C++` then it can be compiled with either compiler and the code is written in `C` and `C++`. Presumably OP only used one compiler therefore constraining said code to one group. Levity never hurt anyone (too much).

Comment: SouravGhosh I mean that my main and functions are written in C, apart from one of the function, which is written in C++. Avi Ginsburg I am compiling by using g++. I think I didn't understand you comment, I hope not to have caused troubles with my ambiguous sentence (written in C and C++).

Comment: @claudio when compiling with gpp, add the compilation option `-g` to tell g++ to compile in "debug mode". E.G. : `gpp -g -o foo.o foo.cpp`